# UTF-8 - I don't understand this byte sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, utf-8, nclob

I have a data provider that send me some data supposed to be coded with UTF-8. This data presents this sequence of bytes:

```
28 49 4e 54 e2 80 99 4c 29 20  (INTâ€™L) => "(INT’L)"
```

For some reason when my java program fetch this data and store it in the database, the above sequence becomes:

```
28 49 4e 54 19 4c 29 20        (INT.L) => "(INT\u0019L)"
```

The java program is built on top of hibernate. It first fetches the data from the provider, stores it in an entity and then this entity is persisted in the database (Postgresql).

Why am I loosing the bytes (`e2 80 99` becomes `19`)  ?
How can I avoid this ?

Here is the core method used to transfer the data fetched from the provider to the entity:

```
import java.sql.Clob;

//...

public static String convertStreamToString(Clob clob) throws SQLException {
    if (clob == null) {
        return "";
    }

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clob.getAsciiStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String lig;
        int n = 0;
        while ((lig = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (n > 0) {
                result.append("\n");
            }
            result.append(lig);
            n++;
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         // Exception handling code ...
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
         // Exception handling code ...
    } finally {
        IOUtil.close(br);
    }

    return result.toString();
}

// ...

MyEntity entity = ...
oracle.sql.NCLOB clob = ...
entity.setProperty(convertStreamToString(clob));


@Entity
class MyEntity {
     @Column(name="prop", length=100000)
     private String prop;  

     public void setProperty(String value) {
          this.prop=value;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew all the work is done by Hibernate...

Comment: I want to see how you receive the data from your provider and how you enter it into Hibernate

Comment: Some component that you have strips the high byte from the characters: you would expect to get `\u2019` instead of `\u0019`. As for what causes this, we need to know more about how the data is put in the database and how you get it back out again. I'm pretty confident Hibernate is not a problem.

Comment: Unless you can give us more details, you are unlikely to get anything other than general guesses.

Comment: @Joni It has been a nightmare for months for storing Oracle NCLOB to Postgresql with Hibernate... (we are fighting this bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7035)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `getAsciiStream()` to read the contents of a CLOB. As the name says, this method is usable only for ASCII; it breaks all non-ASCII characters.

Use the [`getCharacterStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#getCharacterStream%28%29) method instead.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(clob.getCharacterStream());
    ....
```

Comment: Well I must admit that the problem came from our workaround... but this workaround came from an Hibernate bug (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7035) !

Answer (score 0):

I think DB column type should support UTF-8. In Oracle this is NVARCHAR, in Postgresql it is something like this

```
create table test (
    utf8fld varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: The data comes from an Oracle database where it is stored as `NCLOB`. This data is stored in Postgresql as `character varying(100000)`. Any impact ?

Comment: I mean if you have VARCHAR or CLOB column and you write a Unicode character like Ё it may be distorted, while NVARCHAR or NCLOB can store any character